# Log to server using php

Tags: java, php, logging

I build a java applet

java applets run from the browser on the user's computer - **locally**.

Nevertheless, I want to keep statistics about user usage of my applet, which means write to log...

I thought about using log4j remote function, but appearantly my web hosting server (ipage) doesn't give the option to run a java server on it.

So, I thought to use php. That way, I can write from the local user computer to my remote server.

My question is - is there a working product for it? (I don't know php, but it seems very simple, so I thought there must be something built for that purpose already...)

Alternatively, do you know of a better or simpler way to log to a remote server?

Comment: `http://example.com/log.php?text=Your+printer+is+out+of+paper`, `<?php file_put_contents('log.txt', $_GET['text'], FILE_APPEND);`.

Comment: you may also write a java.util.logging appender which send data to the server.

Comment: @Marc B, thank you, as easy as it is, it satisfied my needs. If you publish it as an answer I will accept it. Thanks again! :)